# Censoring words in string[] by replacing

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am making a censor program for a game .dll I cannot figure out how to do this. I have a string[] of words and sentences. I have found out how to filter the words and block the messages. Right now I am trying to replace words with * the same length as a word. For example if someone said "fuck that stupid ass" it would come out as `**** that stupid ***`. Below is the code I am using

```
        public void Actionfor(ServerChatEventArgs args)
    {
        var player = TShock.Players[args.Who];
        if (!args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/") || args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/w") || args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/r") || args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/me") || args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/c") || args.Text.ToLower().StartsWith("/party"))
        {
            foreach (string Word in config.BanWords)
            {
                if (player.Group.HasPermission("caw.staff"))
                {
                    args.Handled = false;
                }

                else if (args.Text.ToLower().Contains(Word))
                {
                    switch (config.Action)
                    {
                        case "kick":
                            args.Handled = true;
                            TShock.Utils.Kick(player, config.KickMessage, true, false);
                            break;
                        case "ignore":
                            args.Handled = true;
                            player.SendErrorMessage("Your message has been ignored for saying: {0}", Word);
                            break;
                        case "censor":
                            args.Handled = false;
                            var wordlength = Word.Length;

                            break;
                        case "donothing":
                            args.Handled = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            args.Handled = false;
        }
    }

   public string[] BanWords = { "fuck", "ass", "can i be staff", "can i be admin" };
```

Some places have code something like this under my case "censor"

```
Word = Word.Replace(Word, new string("*", Word.Length));
```

However I always get an error cannot convert string to char and cannot figure out else to do.

Comment: I don't see the code where you are actually comparing the input to the array BanWords

Comment: Edit: Maybe a way to multiply it so if the length of the word stupid is 4 then a character "*" is added until there are four "*" or **** and place that into a char?

Comment: If you're trying to censor words, why would you leave an asterisk for each character of the censored word? You know that if someone says `**** you`, we have a pretty good idea of what they meant. Why not `* you` or `<3 you`? I think that would be awesome! :D

Comment: I'm comparing text said through the game with
 public string[] BanWords I just cannot figure out how to replace it so that * represents its length. As for cupcake that would take an individual word approach.

Comment: @user3437879 - I don't see that line of code

Comment: Side note: while it may be important for your code to use full set of words that should not be used, it may be good idea to avoid such words in public posts - your question will not change if you don't use f-words. There is also no need to use strings instead of enum values for public samples - try to show care for code you post for others to read.

Comment: Another note: your code uses slowest possible way to search sub-strings, so be careful if your "Text" could be long.

Comment: what if the user adds another 'u' to the f-word? Should you replace it with 5 stars? Does it not count as a bad word?

Comment: maybe each bad word could have its own regular expression for non-normal numbers of characters.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is telling you the problem; [the overload of `String` you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) takes a `char` and `int`, not a `string` and `int`.

It's trying to convert the `*` from a string to a char. Replace the double quotes `"` with a single quote `'`.

Answer (score 2):

For `chars`, use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` like this:

```
new string('*', Word.Length)
```

And in your code, you don't need to replace. Simply do:

```
Word = new string('*', Word.Length);
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but it won't allow me to assign it to Word again as it is in a repeat iteration checking for the words and would replace it before it searches through the whole sentence.

Comment: @user3437879 But your code is assigning to the `Word` and I just made it shorter. Is there a typo in your question? You're line is `Word = Word.Replace(Word, new string("*", Word.Length));`.

Comment: Yea that allowed me to fix it so the error no longer occurs. However When I use it as...
    Word = new string('*', Word.Length);
It wont allow me to use it since word is in the foreach variable iteration.

Comment: @user3437879 I don't see your `foreach` code and how you're using the `Word` variable, so it's hard to suggest something, but you may consider change the `foreach` to `for`. Alternatively, you can use another variable `badWord = new string('*', Word.Length);`

Comment: I guess my question is Word is the word or sentence to be censored if I make it                                 var input = Word.Replace(Word, new string('*', wordlength)); it will accept that, however it wont spit out * in the place of whatever word needs to be censored is said any ideas?

Comment: @user3437879 Of course not, that has nothing to do with `foreach`. You need to replace the original message not the Word variable. Something like `args.Text = args.Text.Replace(Word, new string('*', Word.Length));`

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I would need to separate each word of the message, have a foreach loop for each word separated and replace only that split?

Comment: @user3437879 No, you could use `Replace()` on the message for each word.

Comment: How would I go about doing that without replacing the entire message? I'm not quite sure what to use for it.

Comment: @user3437879 Replacing the entire message is easier if the message is not big. Anyway, if you don't want to do that, then you will have to iterate through the message and process it word by word. Obviously that's a lot of work.